# How to prevent Error message in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I keep getting the following error message every time I try to preview what my app will look like:

***Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous build version of your project.Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.***

I am connected to a mac although using windows, I have looked everywhere for the answer and can't find it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can check the OutPut Console in Visual Studio to know what detail error occurs .

Comment: This might happen if you update the Mac to the preview builds. Ensure that the update is a Stable version on the Mac.